# Raspberry Pi: How can I kill an auto-started Tkinter UI?

Tags: python, linux, task

I coded a simple Tkinter UI in python on my Raspberry Pi. By executing this python script the UI starts in full screen by using this code line.

```
Tk.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
```

Then I included an autostart of this script:
For that reason I added the following line of code in the file "sudo nano /etc/profile"

```
sudo python /home/pi/myscript.py
```

Unfortunately, I forgot to program an "Exit-Button". Is there any way to close/kill this task?

Comment: alt+f4 usually works for me or `sudo pkill -9 python`

Comment: Beware that "pkill -9 python" might kill other instances of python, which might break something. Use "ps" to find the PID of the process you want to kill.

Answer (score 1):

```
kill $(pgrep -f myscript.py)
```

The `-f` / `--full` option to `pgrep` tells it to consider the whole command string, instead of just the binary name (`python`). `pkill` may have a similar option to avoid using a subshell, not sure.

Some other people here have suggested using the `-9` flag to kill -- I wouldn't do this unless the process doesn't respond to a normal kill first.

Comment: you should just do `pkill -f myscript.py`